# Can motherboard heatsink screws change the inductance of nearby traces?

Tags: impedance, heatsink, board

I have bought motherboard and heat sink. The heat sink uses metal screws and the screw heads are isolated from the board with thin mica insulators. But the screws end up being above some traces on the board, thus changing the inductance on some printed wires. The board traces are specially curved like stairs to calibrate inductance and capacitance with each other, and I think these metal screws near them will change their impedance. I am not sure how much the screws of the heat sink will affect the motherboard but it is obvious that they will change the impedance of some of the printed traces.

Do you think that this is major problem and I should avoid this kind of heat sink?

Comment: Your question would be much better comprehended if you could illustrate it with a photo or diagram of what you are doing and what you think is going to happen

Comment: How is this in any way "off topic"?

Comment: Very unlikely this is a issue, but if you're worried about it get nylon screws and then wave a dead fish over it during a full moon for good measure.

Answer (score 5):

Does the screws affect the impedance of the traces?  Probably.

Does it affect the trace impedance in any significant way?  Probably not.

Do I think it is a major problem?  Absolutely not.

Should you avoid that kind of heat sink?  I have never heard of a heat sink making a motherboard not work (due to impedance).  If a motherboard is that sensitive then I would avoid the motherboard, not the heatsink.

The influence on impedance is greatly dependent on distance, and once the distance is more than about 0.1 inches there is almost zero practical effect.  A distance of even 0.03+ inches is still quite minimal.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the inductance of a trace can be increased by the proximity of highly permeable material which acts as an inductor core. The only unknown as are how much, and does it matter?

You say that the screws are made of metal, but of importance is the question which metal? Metals vary greatly in their permeability. That of [aluminum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29#Values_for_some_common_materials) doesn't differ much from the permeability of air, plastic or wood.

The basic litmus test would be to see whether the screws are attracted to a permanent magnet. This confirms paramagnetism or ferromagnetism which is associated with high permeability. If the screws aren't attracted to a magnet, then they probably will not have enough of an effect to matter (especially given that they probably don't matter even if they are ferromagnetic).  In any case, if they are attracted to a magnet, they can be replaced with aluminum screws which have the same diameter and thread pitch, and suitable length and head style.

Also, do the screws approach the traces simply because of excess shaft length? If so, get shorter screws, or cut and file the existing ones.